# How to Fix setVideoSource Failed

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-camera, mediarecorder

I'm trying to implement a camera in my application. The main code is in a Fragment. When called I get this Error setVideoSoruce Failed. 
Couldn't find the answer in other questions.
..........................................................................

Tried changing permissions and adding more but didn't work.

Here is the Error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.sozoapp, PID: 28002
java.lang.RuntimeException: setVideoSource failed.
    at android.media.MediaRecorder._setVideoSource(Native Method)
    at android.media.MediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.java:750)
    at com.example.sozoapp.Fragments.ThiefFragment.initRecorder(ThiefFragment.java:92)
    at com.example.sozoapp.Fragments.ThiefFragment.onCreateView(ThiefFragment.java:56)
    at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2612)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:874)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1228)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1293)
    at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:439)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManagerImpl.java:2066)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1856)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1811)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1717)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl$2.run(FragmentManagerImpl.java:150)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6981)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1445)
     I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 28002 SIG: 9
     Application terminated.
```

Fragment:

```
package com.example.sozoapp.Fragments;


import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.media.MediaRecorder;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;

import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

import com.example.sozoapp.R;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Random;

public class ThiefFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener, SurfaceHolder.Callback {

private Button btnStartRec;
MediaRecorder recorder;
SurfaceHolder holder;
boolean recording = false;
private int randomNum;

private PlacesFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

public ThiefFragment(){

}


public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}

public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_thief, container, false );
    recorder = new MediaRecorder();
    initRecorder();
    btnStartRec =  view.findViewById(R.id.btnCaptureVideo);
    btnStartRec.setOnClickListener(this);
    SurfaceView cameraView = view.findViewById(R.id.surfaceCamera);
    holder = cameraView.getHolder();
    holder.addCallback(this);
    holder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
    cameraView.setClickable(true);
    cameraView.setOnClickListener(this);


    return view;
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);

}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    mListener = null;
}

@SuppressLint({ "SdCardPath", "NewApi" })
private void initRecorder() {

    Random random = new Random();
    int max = 100000;
    int min = 000001;
    int range = max - min + 1;
    randomNum = random.nextInt(range) + min + 1 - 10;


    recorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);
    recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
    recorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.MPEG_4_SP);

    if (this.getResources().getConfiguration().orientation != Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE){
        recorder.setOrientationHint(90);
    } else {
        recorder.setOrientationHint(180);

    }

    recorder.setOutputFile("/sdcard/MediaSozoVideos"+randomNum+ ".mp4");
}

private void prepareRecorder(){
    recorder.setPreviewDisplay(holder.getSurface());
    try {
        recorder.prepare();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(final View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {


}


@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    prepareRecorder();

}

@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {

}

@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    try {
        if (recording){
            recorder.stop();
            recording = false;
        }
        recorder.release();
    }catch (Exception e){

    }

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()){
        case R.id.btnCaptureVideo:
            try {
                if (recording){
                    recorder.stop();
                    recording = false;
                } else {
                    recording = true;
                    recorder.start();
                }
            }catch (Exception e){

            }
            default:
                break;
    }

}
}
```

XML File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<SurfaceView
android:id="@+id/surfaceCamera"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<Button
android:id="@+id/btnCaptureVideo"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:text="Start Recording" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Manifest File Permissions:

```
<!--
     The ACCESS_COARSE/FINE_LOCATION permissions are not required to use
     Google Maps Android API v2, but you must specify either coarse or 
  fine
     location permissions for the 'MyLocation' functionality.
-->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_VIDEO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" 
/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" 
/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera2.full" />



<dist:module dist:instant="true" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
```

Comment: have you been able to solve the problem?